# How to run isort via ALE in Vim?

Tags: python, vim, virtualenv, isort, vim-ale

I want to set up `isort` to be used in Vim via the [ALE](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale) plugin. I've added this shortcut to my `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <leader>I :ALEFix isort<CR>
```

However, when I activate it nothing happens. I have `isort` installed both globally and in the virtualenv. Could anyone give me a hint how to debug/solve this issue?

Answer (score 9):

From ALE's [README.md](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/blob/master/README.md#usage-fixing)

> ALE can fix files with the ALEFix command. Functions need to be configured either in each buffer with a b:ale_fixers, or globally with g:ale_fixers.
> The recommended way to configure fixers is to define a List in an ftplugin file.

The proper way of configuring `isort` is by setting `g:ale_fixers` in your `vimrc` / `init.vim` or `b:ale_fixers` in `ftplugin/python.vim`.

E.g.

```
" setting it globally
let g:ale_fixers = {
            \ 'python': ['black', 'isort'],
            \ }
```

Any command line options you want to pass to isort you do it by setting `g:ale_python_isort_options`.

```
let g:ale_python_isort_options = '--profile black -l 100'
```

> If you want to automatically fix files when you save them, you need to turn a setting on in vimrc.

```
" Set this variable to 1 to fix files when you save them.
let g:ale_fix_on_save = 1
```